# Git: Rebase or Merge to update a local branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Alright, I have a development branch that is tracked remotely and shared by everyone on this project.

Locally I have branched off of this to do some ongoing work.  However, in the mean time another developer has committed and pushed changes to the development branch that I would like reflected in my local branch.  **Is this the time to rebase?**

I don't want to simply commit my local branch to development and then start a new branch because I would like to maintain my commit history.

As I understand it, rebase would take the development branch at HEAD and re-apply all of my commits over top of it, but will that overwrite the other developer's changes without throwing a conflict if we have made changes to the same lines?

Comment: Why not store your changes into a patch, pull his changes, and then apply your patch?

Comment: @shortstuffsushi I may be misunderstanding you (I know almost nothing about patch), but I don't see how pulling will get his changes into my private branch.  Only to my local copy of the development branch.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi;  **git rebase** will do that automatically, so why make things more difficult?

Comment: @itsbruce That may be the case, I've just never had success with rebasing. I've never really working on a clean tree, though.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi You should always be working with a clean tree. Most of Git's features (rebase, quickly switching between branches or back into history, bisect) work so much better if you don't have extra cruft lying around. Use your `.gitignore` so that you don't have extra files getting in your way, and use `git stash` if you have half-finished changes that you're not ready to commit. `git status` should report that there's nothing to commit unless you are actively working on something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you fetch, then you rebase.  You don't clobber the other guy's changes by doing this; what you do is redo your changeset so that it's a delta against his changes rather than the earlier version.  It eliminates unnecessary and unhelpful merge messages from the logs and makes the log more meaningful **if** this is really how the development history should be represented.

Go ahead and rebase; sounds like the right thing to do in this case. way too many people just **git pull** without thinking.

Comment: +1 for "way too many people just **git pull** without thinking".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are right that rebase will take the head of the development branch, and re-apply all of your commits on it.

No, it will not overwrite other developers changes without throwing a conflict. If there is a conflicting change, you will need to resolve the conflicts, just like in a merge (fix the conflicts, and use `git add` to stage the fix), and then tell rebase to continue using `git rebase --continue`.

Yes, this is an appropriate time to do a rebase. That's how a lot of people work; if they have unpushed local commits, and there are upstream commits, they rebase their local commits before continuing to work or pushing to a public repo.